# How to determine whether an array object has a value, and then return the array of objects with this value

Tags: javascript

How to determine whether an array object has a value, and then return the array of objects with this value.  Because I'm a novice, I tried to write it, but I didn't, give an example：

```js
const menu = [
  {
    title: "one",
    children: [{name: "hello"}, {name: "bye"}],
  },{
    title: "two",
    children: [{name: "good"}, {name: "bad"}],
  },
]
```

Assume input **`"bad"`**, the result should be:

```js
menu = [
  {
    title: "two",
    children: [{name: "good"}, {name: "bad"}],
  }
]
```

How to do it？

Comment: *"I don't have any code to show"* is not not the way to ask a question with a specific problem (read: [ask]).

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the array and then filter each element and its `children` like so:

```js
const menu=[{title:"one",children:[{name:"hello",},{name:"bye",},],},{title:"two",children:[{name:"good",},{name:"bad"}]}];

const filterName = toFilter => {
  return menu.filter(({ children }) => {
    return children.some(({ name }) => name == toFilter);
  });
};

console.log(filterName("bad"));
console.log(filterName("good"));
console.log(filterName("neither"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, don't get engaged with fancy Array methods and use simple loops. Try to use a `for loop` to loop over the `menu` array. Then for each item, loop over `children` property of the object. If `name` key matches with your desired output, you can push the whole object in your answer array:

```js
const menu = [
      {
        title: "one",
        children: [
          {
            name: "hello",
          },
          {
            name: "bye",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: "two",
        children: [
          {
            name: "good",
          },
          {
            name: "bad",
          },
        ],
      },
]
let ans = [];
for(let i = 0 ; i < menu.length;i++){
if(menu[i].children){
  for(let j = 0 ; j < menu[i].children.length; j++){
    if(menu[i].children[j].name === 'bad') ans.push(menu[i]);
  }
}
}

console.log(ans);
```

**NOTE:** The above assumes `children` is an array.

Comment: Why should they not "get engaged with fancy Array methods"?